# Is it possible to attach to multiple small objects to a larger one? (Chainmail)

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to create a scale armor in Blender with real individual scales, and I saw this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3weZR0eZcI4

It shows the user adding tons of scales onto a base mesh by their normals in Zbrush from what I understand.

Is it possible to have a similar effect in Blender?

Blend file:

[image]

Comment: not sure what you mean by "adding tons of scale" but to do the same kind of object you can use Instancing or Hair

Comment: or geometry nodes...

Comment: @moonboots I guess "tons of scales" means very very many scales.  ;)

Comment: @ Gordon Brinkmann ooh ok aha  :)  I thought he was talking about scaling something

Comment: I thought a "scale armor" made it clear which scales were meant... but maybe it's because I'm a nerd  :D

Answer (score 4):

There are at least 3 solutions: **Tissue** addon, **Instancing** and **Hair**. I'll let Chris explain the *Geometry Nodes* solution  ;)  Edit: If you work with mirrored or symmetrized mesh, there will be a problem of orientation. I haven't found any easy solution, the best is probably to make the instances real and symmetrize so that both sides are coherent.

**Tissue** addon:

Create 2 objects, the costume and the scale, activate the *Tissue* addon, select the scale, shift select the costume, open the *N panel > Edit > Tissue Tools* and press *Tessellate*. The advantage of this solution is that the scale size will automatically match with the costume face size:

[image]

**Instancing:**

This time, parent the scale to the costume:

[image]

Select your costume, go into the *Object* panel > *Instancing* > click on *Faces*:

[image]

The scale will be instanced along the same shape as the costume, put it over the costume, rotate the scale mesh in *Edit* mode so that it's correctly oriented:

[image]

If you want to malipulate each scale, select them and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Make Instance Real*. If you want to make each scale unique, select them all and go into the *Object* panel > *Relations > Make Single User > Object & Data*.

**Hair:**

Give a particle system to your costume object, choose *Hair*, enable *Advanced*, count the number of faces of your object (enable *Statistics* in the *Viewport Overlays* panel), in *Emission* set the same *Number*, choose *Source > Faces*, disable *Random Order*, set *Particles/Face* to 1, enable *Rotation*, choose *Orientation Axis > Normal*, under *Render* choose *Render As > Object*, select your scale object in *Instance Object*, plays with the *Scale*. Then rotate the scale mesh in Edit mode so that it's correctly oriented.

[image]

Comment: Sadly, none of these are working. Tissue makes holes in the mesh and the other methods have the scales too far apart and one side is always flipped. I think It's better I place what my file here.

Comment: yes I've also noticed this problem when I've made mine, can't put my finger on why the instances are sometimes flipped, it doesn't happen if you don't use any Mirror or Symmetrize though, I can't tell why for the moment

Comment: Hmmm....I wouldn't mind going the texture route since this seems to be a difficult thing to achieve in Blender. But I don't really know how to make a good texture like that. That was my first attempt and it wasn't a very good one.

Comment: I'm not sure there's any solution, the best is probably to symmetrize once you've made your scales real. Then you can bake the normals to make your object lighter.

Comment: I've been experimenting with arrays, surface deform and shrinkwrap modifiers to see if I can place it on top of the mesh. I've gotten some interesting results. If I figure something out I'll post it here as an answer.